# php null coalescing operator in combination with concatenation operator does not work right

Tags: php

This code echo "2" instead of "2some text"!

```php
$x = 2;
echo $x??0 . "some text";
```

If we put the `$x??0` in parentheses, the result is correct:

```php
$x = 2;
echo ($x??0) . "some text";
```

now result is: `2some text`

Is something wrong in the above code or is a php bug?

Comment: No need to concatenate output with echo using a `.`. You can use a `,` (comma) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the correct behavior. The string concatenation `.` operator has higher precedence than the null coalesce operator `??`, so (as you've noted) you need to use parens to force the desired behavior. Without parens, the code is interpreted as if you had done this:

```
echo $x ?? (0 . "some text");
```

See [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) for details.

Comment: may be worth noting that without the brackets around the `$x??0` - it's comparing 2 vs `0.some Text` - which of course renders 2 because $x is not null