# Null Coalesce Operator not working php string

Tags: php, coalesce

I have a log error that results in null depending on the session.

I want to create an error log but if the variable is null, put another result.

This way it **works**.
`error_log($proxy ?? '127.0.0.1');`

**But not like** this when I add a string to it.
`error_log("Uso del servidor: " . $proxy ?? '127.0.0.1');`

Why?

What would be the proper way to do it? I need it with string to identify it.

Comment: Related: [php null coalescing operator in combination with concatenation operator does not work right](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58734145/2943403)

Answer (score 1):

Because the string concatenation (`.`) has a higher precedence than the null coalescing operator (`??`), you need to do it like the following:

```
error_log( "Uso del servidor: " . ($proxy ?? '127.0.0.1') );
```

Reference: [php operator precedence](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Answer (score 0):

Solved: `error_log("Uso del servidor: " . ($proxy ?? '127.0.0.1'));`

I needed to add the parentheses